# Simular o funcionamento de um processador usando java swing

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, swing

Preciso simular o funcionamento de uma processador, usando conceitos de fila. Este processador será de cores, onde o usuario adiciona a cor que deseja ser processada e o seu tempo de execuçao, essa cor precisa entrar numa fila de espera, na medida que o usuario adicionar mais cores,  essa fila de espera precisa esta na ordem e ser redimensionada na tela , caso o usuario necessite remover uma cor, essa remoçao sera feita nas primeiras cores que adicionei.

OBs: toda essa tela foi feita somente arrastando os componentes do java swing. 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Consegui adicionar os botoes a lista de espera:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    String cores = (String) cor.getSelectedItem();
    String seg = (String) segundos.getSelectedItem();
    JButton b1 = new JButton(cores + "/" + seg);
    b1.setSize(10, 10);
    b1.setVisible(true);

    queue.enqueue(new ColorTime(cores, 5));

    jPanel1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    jPanel1.add(b1);
    jPanel1.updateUI();
    //setting flow layout of right alignment
}
```

e na opçao start ele ta chamando a primeira cor que estava na lista de espera, agora quero pegar o seu tempo, executa-lo e passar para a proxima cor da lista. Como criar um contador regressivo com o tempo que passei junto com a cor?

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    //Timer timer;
    //timer = new Timer();
    //timer.s
    while (item != null) {

        item = queue.dequeue();

        if (item != null) {
            switch (item.color) {
                case "Azul":
                    jPanel2.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                    jTextField1.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                    jTextField2.setText(item.color);
                    Timer t = new Timer(item.getTime(), action);
                    t.start();
                    break;
                case "Verde":
                    jPanel2.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                    jTextField1.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                    jTextField2.setText(item.color);

                    break;
                case "Vermelho":
                    jPanel2.setBackground(Color.RED);
                    jTextField1.setBackground(Color.RED);
                    jTextField2.setText(item.color);
                    break;
                case "Cinza":
                    jPanel2.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                    jTextField1.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
                    jTextField2.setText(item.color);
                    break;
                case "Preto":
                    jPanel2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                    jTextField1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                    jTextField2.setText(item.color);
                    break;
                case "Roxo":
                    jPanel2.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
                    jTextField1.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
                    jTextField2.setText(item.color);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Esta não é uma cor válida!");
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Minha classe da lista:

```
public class MyQueue <T> {
    private T[] queue;
    private int front =  0,
        back  =  0,
        size;

    /**
     * Constructs an empty queue with an initial capacity of ten.
    */
    public MyQueue () {
    this.size = 10;
    this.queue = (T[])new Object[size];
    }

    /**
     * Constructs an empty queue with the specified initial capacity.
     * @param size
     */
    public MyQueue (int size) {
    this.size = size;
    this.queue = (T[])new Object[size];
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if the queue contains no elements.
     * @return
     */
    public boolean isEmpty () {
    return back == front;
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if the queue is full.
     * @return
     */
    public boolean isFull () {
    return front == size - 1;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the size of the queue.
     * @return
     */
    public int size () {
    return front - back;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the element that is the end of the queue.
     * If the referenced element does not exist null is returned.
     * @return
     */
    public T front () {
    try {
        return queue[front-1];
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        return null;
    }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the object that is the beginning of the queue
     * If the referenced element does not exist null is returned.
     * @return
     */

    public T back () {
    try {
        return queue[back];
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        return null;
    }
    }

    /**
     * Adds an element in the queue.
     * @param element
     */
    public void enqueue (T element) {   
    if (isFull()) {
        System.out.println("Error: queue overflow");
    } else {
        queue[front++] = element;
    }
    }

    /**
     *  Removes an element in the queuein the queue and return the first element.
         *  In case of error return null.
     * @return
     */
    public T dequeue () {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Error: queue underflow");
        return null;
    } else {
        T item = queue[back++];
        return item;
    }
    }

    /**
     * Removes all elements from the queue.
     */
    public void clear () {
    if (!isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < front; i++) {
            queue[i] = null;
        }
    }
        back = 0;
    front = 0;
    }

    /**
     * Prints all elements that are in the queue.
     */
    public void print () {
    if (!isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = back; i < front; i++) {
            System.out.print(queue[i] + " ");
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Amplo demais para uma pergunta. Tente desenvolver e vai postando perguntas sobre partes bem específicas. Da maneira que está alguém teria não só que desenvolver, mas pensar no modelo, numa especificação mínima. Minha sugestão é a seguinte: Ao invés de preocupar com a interface gráfica, preocupe-se com o seu modelo, com suas classes (atributos, métodos e relacionamentos).

Comment: Vamos por partes. Primeiro você precisa de um modelo. O modelo é um conjunto de classes que modela os seus objetos de negócio: Cores, filas, tempo de processamento, etc. **O seu modelo tem que ser totalmente independente, autocontido e separado do swing.** Depois de pronto o seu modelo, você faz com que o swing fale com ele. Dividindo o seu projeto assim, fica mais fácil para você.

Comment: Também tem o problema de que tem uma estrutura de dados implementada na mão aí. Pode ter bugs nela também.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O modelo não é muito complexo: crie uma classe "Cor" para representar as cores e um ArrayList para representar a fila de cores. Para adicionar ou remover elementos da lista você vai utilizar os métodos add() e remove(), conforme a documentação:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Na interface você precisa de um JPane para desenhar a fila. Crie uma classe nova para isso.

O processamento deverá ser feito em uma Thread separada, já que você precisa ter controle sobre o tempo.