# Criar JLabels Dinamicamente

Tags: java, swing

Eu tenho que criar, a partir de um clique de um botão, um `JLabel` dinamicamente. De forma que esses labels fiquem organizados em uma ordem, atribuindo um nome para esse `JLabel`.

O usuário pode criar quantos labels ele quiser...

Como eu faço isso?

Na minha *action*, tenho isso:

```
String name = "cor";

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    label.setName(name);
    label.setBounds(x, y, 150, 150);
```

Porém, ele não adiciona. Onde estou errando?

Comment: `JLabel label = new JLabel();`. Aí é só definir uma posição, um tamanho, um texto e adicionar o no controle pai.

Comment: como ficaria no codigo? isso tudo ficaria dentro do botao de adicionar?

Comment: Onde você quiser, se vai ficar na action do botão ou criar um método é você que escolhe. Uma pergunta: você está usando algum [layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)?

Comment: `JLabel label = new JLabel(text);  
 label.setName(name);  
 label.setBounds(x, y, 50, 50); `

seria assim?

Comment: falta adicionares ao frame em questão, `teuPanel.add(label);` algo deste género, se estás a adicionar em tempo real, podes ter de atualizar o frame, `teuPanel.revalidate();`  `teuPanel.repaint();`  `teuPanel.pack();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bem, consegui fazer isso que se segue. Ao clicar no botão, labels são adicionados à tela.

```
import java.swing.List;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class CriaBotoes {

    private final JFrame jf;
    private final List<JLabel> lista;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(CriaBotoes::new);
    }

    public CriaBotoes() {
        jf = new JFrame("Teste");
        jf.setBounds(10, 10, 700, 700);
        jf.setLayout(null);

        JButton bt = new JButton("Novo label");
        jf.add(bt);
        bt.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 30);

        lista = new ArrayList<>();

        bt.addActionListener(e -> adicionarLabel());
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void adicionarLabel() {
        int n = lista.size() + 1;
        String name = "cor " + n;
        JLabel label = new JLabel(name);
        jf.add(label);
        label.setBounds(10, n * 20 + 20, 150, 20);
        lista.add(label);
    }
}
```

Comment: Victor essa duvida é justamente pra se aplicar nessa questao: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/138609/simular-o-funcionamento-de-um-processador-usando-java-swing

Comment: [off-topic] @Victor Stafusa estas expressões ( `CriaBotoes::new` `e -> adicionarLabel()`) pertencem ao Java 8 certo!?

Comment: @jsantos1991 sim, é uma expressão lambda, do java 8.

Comment: @jsantos1991 O primeiro é um caso de *method reference* (ou para ser mais exato *constructor reference*) e o segundo é um *lambda*. Sim, são novas expressões do Java 8. O equivalente em Java 7 seria `new Runnable() { @Override public void run() { new CriaBotoes(); }}` e `new ActionListener() { @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { adicionarLabel(); }}` - Como se vê, essas novas características da linguagem a deixam bem menos verbosa.